# Can a sphere exist in the fourth dimension the same way cubes do?

Tags: geometry

My idea is that they can't, but i'm not sure, you know that a cube in the fourth dimension is like a cube attached to a square from its edges, or a cube in a cube,
 which moves to form a cube coming out of another cube and so on.so my idea would be that spheres don't exist in the fourth dimension, but rather it is circles that do, as circles can be embedded into another to form complex 4D shapes, and this means that **MAYBE** circles are in fact 4D and 2D OBJECTS[image]

Comment: "a cube in the fourth dimension is like a cube attached to a square from its edges, or a cube in a cube, which moves to form a cube coming out of another cube and so on". What you are referring to is not a 4D cube, but rather the projection of a 4D cube onto the 3D space.

Comment: Yeah, but can a sphere be projected from the fourth dimension into the third dimension

Comment: I think this is actually a mathematical question so I'd be inclined to send it to [math.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the definition of a sphere offered in the answer by @bemjanim, a sphere is the set of points equidistant from a single point.  So, the equations for a sphere in 2D and 3D are:
$$x^2 +y^2 = R^2,$$

and
$$x^2+y^2+z^2 = R^2.$$

In 4D, the equation would be:
$$w^2 +x^2 +y^2 +z^2 = R^2.$$

Note that for any fixed value of $w$, the values of $x, y$ and $z$ trace out a sphere of radius $\sqrt {R^2 -w^2}$.  So, the equation actually describes points $x, y$, and $z$ that *fill* the 3D sphere's volume as the value of $w$ is varied from $R$ to zero.  So, it's reasonable to say that, if considered from the right perspective, a $solid$ sphere is the 3D projection of the 4D version of a sphere.

Answer (score 3):

A sphere can exist in any number of dimensions. It is defined as the set of points equidistant from the centre. This definition includes the three dimensional sphere and the circle, which is a sphere in the plane.

Comment: Do you mean that spheres can exist in the fourth dimension exactly the way they are in the third dimension.

Comment: Yes. 1-, 2- and 3-spheres can be embedded within 4 dimensional space.